# ggplot polar plots text is cut off

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I'm attempting to find a way to remove the text that gets cut off from the edges on a polar plot using ggplot (see attachment).  I've tried manipulations in theme, text and geom_text using vjust,hjust,nudge_y...etc. and I cannot make them move at all.

```
ggplot(ds, aes(factor(TraitIds), UserDat, fill = factor(TraitIds))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:1) + 
  coord_polar() +
  geom_text_repel(nudge_y=0.3)+
  labs(x = "Raw Trait Scores", y = "") +
  theme( panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                                        colour = "white",
                                        size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "black"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        text = element_text( face = "plain",
                            colour = "black", size = 10,
                            hjust = 100, vjust = 1000, angle = 0,
                            lineheight = 0.9),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the dataset you made the plot with?

Comment: no, i cannot, but my issue is with plotting the data, hence my issues are with the ggplot tool itself and options with it.

Comment: this seems to be a solutino
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373422/changing-the-radius-of-a-coord-polar-ggplot/28846989#28846989

Comment: If you found a solution you should put your final code as an answer or have this marked as a duplicate.  It can be difficult to troubleshoot coding questions without a [minimal and reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).